# Python While Loop Condition Using Time

Tags: python

I want to make a while loop which uses `time.sleep()` every 5 minutes then continues the process. But the problem is that my code is not working properly. I'm using this code below. What can be the problem in my code and what should I do to make it work?

```
with open('url.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8', errors='ignore') as des:
    description = des.readline()
    timeout = time.time() + 60*5
    while description:
        test = 0
        description = des.readline()
        browser.get(description)       
        time.sleep(6)

        if test == 5 or time.time() > timeout:
            time.sleep(timeout)
            continue
```

Comment: test==5 will never be true as per the code given. Also time.sleep(timeout) will sleep for time.time() + 60*5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing all your code or having more description, it is difficult to determine what the problem is. If you want the loop to execute once overy five minutes, you would use `time.sleep(5*60)` because `time.sleep()` works in seconds, not minutes. Also, `if test == 5` will never be true because you set `test = 0` in the loop, then never change it. If `description` is `False`, than the `while` loop will never execute. Make sure that `description` is true and that you change the `test` variable or remove it from the `if` statement. It also looks like to repeat the line `description = des.readline()`, which should not be changing at all.

Comment: I think this should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: The logic with `description` is actually a good one, because if there's nothing in file to read, then there will be nothing to execute with `while` statement.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because of your `time.sleep(timeout)` line.

It basically means - pause for [seconds from epoch](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time) + 5minutes, therefore it'll run only one time and then it runs almost something like `time.sleep(infinity)` - at least for your machine.

It sleeps well.. for a long time.

Also, the `test` variable will never be `==5`, because you are not incrementing it. Move the variable outside `while` and after `browser.get(description)` put `test += 1`. And in the second line is a typo, it should be `des.readlines()` if I'm right.